# Listing files in the current directory which are controlled by Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a few directories containing some files which are part of the Hg repository and some which are not. How do I list the files in the current directory which are part of the repository?

I know that

```
hg status | grep "\? Path/To/Dir/In/Repo"
```

gets me all the files which are *not* part of the repository so I could invert the regular expression, but "hg status" also takes a long time on a large repository so a solution that doesn't need that would be ideal.

Also, if possible, the solution should not need any extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Use `hg locate`.  (`hg help locate` for details...)

`hg locate --include . --exclude ./*/* --fullpath` will list all the tracked files in the current directory, but not any of the subdirectories.  If you don't care about the full path you can exclude the `--fullpath` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that `hg locate` is deprecated as of Mercurial 3.2, so use

```
hg files
```

It takes the same options, so

```
hg files --include . --exclude ./*/*
```

still works for showing only files in the current dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can get state of all files in the repository as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000095/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-repository-in-mercurial-hg). Unfortunately, I'm not a guru of shell, so you will need to make some output processing above the result of command.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
hg locate --include ./*.*
```